# problema con push.js en web

Tags: jquery, html

amigos hola, bueno les comento que ando implementando la función de notificaciones de parte de la librería de https://pushjs.org/ y tengo este código que dejaré abajo y se supone que lo saque de la página para testearlo en mi localhost pero no funciona y eso que se supone que es extremadamente sencillo, ¿acaso esa librería necesita algún parámetro adicional?

> perdón por no dejar el código aquí pero no sé porque pero se daña cuando lo pongo, discúlpen.

[enlace del código por pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wL070aGh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código es correcto, lo mas seguro es que tengas una restricción del navegador por ejecutar la notificación directamente desde el archivo html, suele ocurrir con `Chrome`, prueba en `firefox`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si insistes con `Chrome` entonces podrías probar subiendo el código a un servidor, como tu hosting o instalar un servidor simple como `WAMP` http://www.wampserver.com/en/ que es para PHP.

Subes tus archivos a la carpeta `www` de `wamp`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

e ingresas desde el `localhost`, asi `chrome` no lo restringiría.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ándale que mal, que eso pero bueno se ya al menos que funciona entonces, pues también lo quería para notificar por medio de chrome móvil en el android, gracias amigo intentaré por otro navegador.